# how to send data via ajax from view to controller on codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i tried to send data from view to controller , but nothing work "ajax return error" i try all ways those i see in other similar question 
My view:

```
var pdata ={
    "latitude": lat,
    "longitude": log
};
latlog = "/"+1;
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/users/search"+CityINP+distINPx+CategoryINP+textINP+latlog,
    type: "POST",
    data: pdata,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
        // if success reload ajax table
         alert("success");
        // reload_table();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error adding / update data');
    }
});
```

my controller:

```
public function search($city=null,$dist=null,$cate=null,$text=null,$latlon=null)
{
}
```

Comment: You can check the contents of textStatus and errorThrown. Ajax may tell you itself what's wrong, this is what those parameters are for.

Comment: what is the actual issue that you are facing??

Comment: I think it might be with your ajax's url, check your slashes `/` between the parameters

Comment: @MAZux 
Parameters already had slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I will suggest you to  make a js variable in header section like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>
```

In this way, you won't have to write echo baseurl everytime in the URL.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: BASE_URL + "controllerName/search",
    data: {'CityINP': distINPx,'CategoryINP':latlog },
    success: function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    if(data.response == "response")
    {
        //do anything you want from the response you get
    }
 }
});
```

To get the parameters in the controller function you can get it by the following code

```
$this->input->post('CityINP');
$this->input->post('CategoryINP');
```

Answer (score 0):

change your url
 url: "index.php/users/search"+CityINP+distINPx+CategoryINP+textINP+latlog,

to  url: "index.php/users/search/"+CityINP+distINPx+CategoryINP+textINP+latlog,

"/" after search function name, in your url all variables are concat with search funaction name.

Comment: why??
if url doesn't get its correct function name how data will pass ??? and value will return?